# Discord Rich Prescence timestamp & name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a discord bot in JS that when the command is called says "User has been playing GameName for Hours". My code currently works if the mentioned user is playing a game that lacks rich prescence support, but if a game like League of legends is called alongside the user, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'presence' of undefined`. While I know what this means, it is the way I reference the mentioned user's presence found in the code below.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    aliases: [],
    category: 'test',
    utilisation: '',

    execute(client, message, presence, guild) {
        let msgMention = message.mentions.members.first()

        let mp = msgMention.presence.activities[0]

        if (msgMention.presence.activities[0].name == "Spotify"){
            var imgvar = mp.assets.largeImage
            var imgvar = imgvar.replace('spotify:','')
            message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    color: '1DB954',
                    title: `${msgMention.displayName} is listening to ${mp.assets.largeText} for some reason`,
                    image: {
                        url: `https://i.scdn.co/image/${imgvar}`
                    },
                },
            });
        } else if (mp.name == "League of Legends") {
            const n = new Date();
            console.log(n)
            const g = mp.timestamps.start;
            if (g <= 0) {
                return;
            }
            const hours = Math.abs(n - g) / 36e5;
            const minutes = hours.toFixed(2)
            message.channel.send(`${msgMention.displayName} has been wasting his life playing ${mp.name} for ${minutes} hours`);
        } else {
            const n = new Date();
            console.log(n)
            const g = mp.timestamps.start;
            if (g <= 0) {
                return;
            }
            const hours = Math.abs(n - g) / 36e5;
            const minutes = hours.toFixed(2)
            message.channel.send(`${msgMention.displayName} has been playing ${mp.name} for ${minutes} hours`);
        }
    },
};
```

The math works calculating time, along with the seperate spotify command working as well, but league of legends simply doesnt work due to it having rich prescence support, how can I fix this error to reference it for normal non-rich presence games while Rich prescence games still grab the name of the activity

Comment: Did you mention any member in the message?

Comment: yes, the command works fully for anything that isnt a rich prescence

Comment: The error seems to be from the reason that msgMention is undefined which points out that no one was mentioned in the message, can you log `msgMention`?

Comment: I have and it does the same thing, like I said rich presence is a unique scenario, I am 100% mentioning somebody and it works as intended with a non rich presence game or Spotify.

Comment: Finbar, presences are also sent on guildCreate, so no issues about no presences

Comment: If LoL presence command doesn't work, can you include the whole stack of the error and which line the error is at? Plus, does it even resolve the mention member, if at all?

Comment: Thankyou for notifying me. I've deleted the false comment.

Comment: ```let mp = msgMention.presence.activities[0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'presence' of undefined at Object.execute (/commands/test.js:12:29) at module.exports (/events/message.js:13:18) at Client.emit (events.js:400:28) at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14) at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)``` Error is at line 11, being the mp variable declaration

Comment: Sorry for a late response, it seems like discord.js is not resolving the mention, but that shouldn't be an issue with presences of one being Spotify and one being LoL 

Comment: Do you know of any solutions to that?

Answer (score 0):

User activity

```
  let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]) || message.guild.member(message.author)
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

if (!member.presence.activities || member.presence.activities.length == 0) {
    embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', 'Not playing anything')
} else {
    const activity = member.presence.activities[0];
    embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', `${activity.type} ${activity.name}\n${activity.details}\n${activity.state}`);
}
```